# Generar URL con php

Tags: php

la verdad no sé como detallar en el titulo lo que necesito hacer,

requiero lo siguiente:

Tengo una imagen que dice "CONSULTE SUS DOCUMENTOS AQUÍ" Al darle clic necesito que salga una ventana solicitando numero de RUC (documento de identidad comercial Peru), la persona debe introducir su codigo y darle a un boton que diga VER, ese botón deberá redirigirla a una dirección predeterminada: https://pagina.com/fe?empr= a la que se le sumará su codigo quedando de la siguiente manera :

https://mipagina.com/fe?empr=xxxxxxxxxxx donde las xxxx representan al código que introdujo la persona..

Alguien me orienta como podría realizar esto? es en Wordpress que requiero poner el botón.

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para lo mismo.Saludos.

Comment: Por otra parte tu problema puede resolverse de varias maneras, con javascript  o incluso solo con php, depende, agrega el código que tienes para poder darte una respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que entiendes de wordpress y sabes como usar código php en tu web, una solución sería crear un formulario html de esta manera.

```
<form action="https://mipagina.com/fe" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="empr" placeholder="Introduce tu número RUC"/>
    <input type="submit" value="VER"/>
</form>
```

Al hacer click en VER te debería enviar a https://mipagina.com/fe?empr=xxxxxxxxx

Para recoger el valor debes usar este código

```
<?php
    $empr = "";

    if(isset($_GET['empr']){
        $empr = $_GET['empr'];
    }
?>
```

Con eso ya tendrías tu código en una variable, ya solo quedaría operar con ella o mostrarla por pantalla. `echo $empr;`

Comment: Correcto, si tengo nociones de como hacerlo funcionar en Wordpress, lo aplicaré y te comento.
Agradecido desde ya.